# MatToolbar throws error when using it with Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular version 9.2.0

When I import the `MatToolbarModule` in a module and use it in the html template, then I get the following error message:

> This likely means that the library (@angular/material/toolbar) which declares MatToolbarModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
>
> ```
> 8 export declare class MatToolbarModule {
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> src/app/angular-material.module.ts:53:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of ComponentsModule, but itself has errors
> ```

Does anyone face the same issue?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Add below specific configuration in `package.json` and `npm install`.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  }
}
```

**Reference**: https://angular.io/guide/ivy#speeding-up-ngcc-compilation

Comment: I have fixed it without the ngcc.
I am working with Angular 9 and during the npm i material he took the version 10 of angular/material.
I have changed from npm i into ng add angular/material and then it worked.

Comment: For me it worked , just closed the running instance , npm install and done...

Comment: Appreciate adding the link to the docs so we're not just blindly changing the project config!

Comment: Another one possibility will be to update Angular 9 to 11 :

https://update.angular.io/?v=9.1-11.0

It work perfectly : Just take in account first step for this upgrade :

*Before Updating*

If you depend on many Angular libraries you may consider speeding up your build by invoking the ngcc (Angular Compatibility Compiler) in an npm postinstall script via small change to your package.json.

Comment: The better solution here is noted in @TheCoderGuy comment using "ng add angular/material". This maintains the version number and compatibility and sets up any dependencies needed all while fulfilling this bug reported

Answer (score 90):

I had the same problem before, its because you modify your `app.module.ts` file while the server is running.
Try to stop it and then run it again using the `ng serve`command.

Comment: I was having the same issue with MatListModule and stop/restart server was the solution

Comment: Anybody have an idea why this necessary?  It works for me, but I hate when "have you tried turning it off and on again?" solves the issue with no insight as to the true problem.  Not faulting the answer btw (I upvoted) but just curious more than anything.

Comment: doing this alone wasn't enough for me. i had to also remove `node_modules`, and run `yarn` again

Answer (score 71):

This used to happen to me whenever I imported 'MatToolbar' 'MatDialog' instead of 'MatToolbarModule' or 'MatDialogModule'.

Comment: Yes we have to import module that contains component and not component directly.

Comment: This was it. I've imported MatSnackBar instead of MatSnackBarModule

Comment: Yes that helped well, ut what about MatDataSource, it doesn't have module and says datasource is not a table

Comment: oh my, you saved my day 

Answer (score 11):

I faced similar problem with MatDatePicker. The problem was that I had imported `MatDatepicker` instead of importing `MatDatepickerModule` in the `app.module.ts` file.

So, check that you have imported MODULE not Component in your module file.

Answer (score 4):

I found an error in imports section, i've added unexisting item.

```
import { MatMenuItem } from '@angular/material/menu';
```

and MatMenut item doesn't exist, i changed in MatMenuModule and after works

Answer (score 4):

So I was just having a similar issue, and I was able to fix it by rearranging my import modules.

In my case, I was calling `LoadingBarRouterModule` before the main module `LoadingBarModule`. Check to see if you are loading the `MatToolbarModule` module before another required module and move it below that.

Comment: I moved my material module imports to the top of all imports in-app.module.ts file and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the selected answer could not be the correct one because you may want bundle the dependency when you are building the application.

From https://angular.io/guide/ivy#speeding-up-ngcc-compilation

> In version 9, the server builder which is used for App shell and
> Angular Universal has the bundleDependencies option enabled by
> default. If you opt-out of bundling dependencies you will need to run
> the standalone Angular compatibility compiler (ngcc).

I'm opting of restarting the server everytime i'm adding a material component into AppModule. But if i'm wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here to me was because I forgot import a module.ts, and the console did not show about it. so, I only imported it and the angular worked ok. You can review all your modules.ts if there are some error with imports.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the node_modules and reinstalled it.

Complete discussion here:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18637

Answer (score 0):

I imported some classes(FormControl, FormGroup, Validators) which are not modules in app.module.ts
I removed those classes and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is importing the whole module for MatToolbar.

```
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
```

And then adding MatToolbarModule to the imports[] array in my app.module.ts.

Answer (score 0):

stop your angular service (if you use command prompt or powershell ctrl + c) and run again(ng serve)

Comment: If you read carefully, you can see that there is already the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to unused (or rather broken) `ValueAccessor`s – removing them fixed this.