# Angular 9.0.7 Ivy: BrowserAnimationsModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy

Tags: angular

I created a new Angular project and get the following error:

> This likely means that the library
>   (@angular/platform-browser/animations) which declares
>   BrowserAnimationsModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or
>   is not compatible with Angular Ivy

My Angular version is: 9.0.7

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079125/mattoolbar-throws-error-when-using-it-with-angular-9) I tried to remove the `node_modules` and reinstall it, but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you try removing the `package-lock.json` file?

Comment: I did removed and removed node_modules and reinstalled still not working

Answer (score 3):

From issue comment from angular repository https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29960#issuecomment-484420080

> If you set "target": "es5" in your tsconfig.app.json, then this bug does not happen.

Answer (score 3):

```
Package.json
 "scripts": {
   "postinstall": "ngcc"
  }

tsConfig.json
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
     "enableIvy": false
  }
```

Delete the node modules folder & Install node_modules: npm i --save

build project: ng build & start project: ng serve