# have been issued with this error ...what can I do?

Tags: angular

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:28:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MatFormField'.

28     MatFormField
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~


ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts:64:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but
```

could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

```
This likely means that the library (@angular/material/form-field) which declares MatFormField has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or
```

is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

```
64 export declare class MatFormField extends _MatFormFieldMixinBase implements AfterContentInit, AfterContentChecked, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, CanColor {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~


ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts:64:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but
```

could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

```
This likely means that the library (@angular/material/form-field) which declares MatFormField has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or
```

is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

```
64 export declare class MatFormField extends _MatFormFieldMixinBase implements AfterContentInit, AfterContentChecked, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, CanColor {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~


ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts:64:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but
```

could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

```
This likely means that the library (@angular/material/form-field) which declares MatFormField has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or
```

is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

```
64 export declare class MatFormField extends _MatFormFieldMixinBase implements AfterContentInit, AfterContentChecked, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, CanColor {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079125/mattoolbar-throws-error-when-using-it-with-angular-9

Comment: I tried to use "postinstall": "ngcc" in package.json file but it sill have bug